# Triggering a python function when tab closes with flask

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to create a modern looking GUI so I decided to setup a simple flask app. Eventually, I want to pack the app up in a .exe file, so I want to start the server and open a web-browser when I start the flask app, and quit the server when I close the tab. My question is:

Is there any way to trigger a python function that quits the flask server when I close the tab?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Probably the most  reliable way would be a web socket connection which eventually closes when the browser closes. Anything else is hardly reliable. Just try to remove false positives if and when the connection closes just temporarily.

Comment: That sounds good! However I don't know how that would be done. It doesn't have to be specially secure. It is a app only I am going to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an event listener to `beforeunload` event and send a request when the tab is about to close.

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => fetch('/stop');
```

When you confirm it, the request is sent, and you can shut down the server inside the handler.

The only downside is that the browser shows a popup, confirming if you really want to leave.

[image]

Comment: Can't that be disabled? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I doubt it, it seems like a security warning. There's an alternative: `navigator.sendBeacon(url)`, which you can find out about here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon